# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) unable to find an inherited method for function ‘krige’ for signature ‘"formula", "tbl_df"’

Tags: methods, kriging, inherited

I have a strange Error and actually don't know how to solve it, even after checking other posts. Everything runs until the Kriging and then I receive the error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) unable to find an inherited method for function ‘krige’ for signature ‘"formula", "tbl_df"’

The strange thing is that everything worked a few days ago, I did not change anything in the code and now it doesn't run anymore. Some other posts related the problem with the Raster, but I could not find any discrepances. Is there something because of recent updates? I use for example the sp package.

Unfortunately I cannot provide the data I use, hopefully it can be solved without.

How can I solve the issue? Thank you in advance for the help.

```
homeDir = "D:/Folder/DataXYyear/"
y = 1992

Source = paste("Year", y, ".csv")
File = file.path(homeDir,Source)
GWMeas <- read_csv(File)

GWMeasX <- na.omit(GWMeas)


ggplot(
  data = GWMeasX,
  mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y, color = level)
) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_viridis(option = "B") +
  theme_classic()


GWMX_sf <- st_as_sf(GWMeasX, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 25832) %>%
  cbind(st_coordinates(.))

v_emp_OK <- gstat::variogram(
  level~1,
  as(GWMX_sf, "Spatial") # switch from {sf} to {sp}
)

v_mod_OK <- automap::autofitVariogram(level~1, as(GWMX_sf, "Spatial"), model = "Sph")$var_model


GWMeasX %>% as.data.frame %>% glimpse
GW.vgm <- variogram(level~1, locations = ~X+Y, data = GWMeasX) # calculates sample variogram values
GW.fit <- fit.variogram(GW.vgm, model=vgm(model =  "Gau")) # fit model


sf_GWlevel <- st_as_sf(GWMeasX, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 25833)

grd_sf <- sf_GWlevel %>%
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc() %>%
  st_make_grid(
    cellsize = c(5000, 5000), # 5000m pixel size
    what = "centers"
  ) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.))

grid <- as(grd_sf, "Spatial") 
gridded(grid) <- TRUE            
grid <- as(grid, "SpatialPixels")

createGrid <- function(XY.Spacing)


crs(grid) <- crs(GWMX_sf)

OK3 <- krige(formula = level~1, # variable to interpolate
  data = GWMX_sf, # gauge data
  newdata = grid, # grid to interpolate on
  model = v_mod_OK, # variogram model to use
  nmin = 4, # minimum number of points to use for the interpolation
  nmax = 20, # maximum number of points to use for the interpolation
  maxdist = 120e3 # maximum distance of points to use for the interpolation
)
```

Comment: Just quessing, but could it be that krige does not accept data in tibble form? Try to run as.data.frame(GWMX_sf) -> GWMX_sf before calling krige.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. I converted the file before in df, but it seemed to not have worked, I needed to convert it by binding the columns manually.